# Copy/paste issue with eclipse Juno

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-juno

I am using Eclipse Juno on Mac OS 10.7.4 and Android ADT.

Some times when copying and pasting code the copy and paste event take place at the previous file that I had opened on the Editor.

It does get fixed restarting Eclipse but it's quite annoying.

Is there a fix out there for this problem?

Comment: I have the same issue on Windows 7

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I got tired of this bug too.

After a search, I've found that it's a problem with ADT 20 on Juno:

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=34630

And got fixed on 20.0.2.

Run a check for updates in Eclipse and update ADT to latest version (currently 20.0.3) and the problem is gone =)

Comment: I think this is fixed now, I haven't had it for a while. There are still other annoyances on how the editor behaves but hope they fix them on next version :)

Comment: I'm having this issues on linux with Juno Service Release 2 without ADT ever installed.

Answer (score 13):

According to this [bug report](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=368354) and this [forum post](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/895704/), unbinding Cmd+C/X/V from Preferences -> General -> Keys seem to solve the
problem.

If not, submit a bug report.

Comment: That seemed to work but now I realised I have this same problem with Cmd+Z and Undo :(

Comment: Well in this case, submit a bug report or up-vote an existing one.

Answer (score 2):

Disabling `Hyperlinking` fixed this for me.  You could also just change the `Default modifier key` to something other than `Ctrl` if you still want to use hyperlinking.

Go to **Window** -> **Preferences** -> **General** -> **Editors** -> **Text Editors** -> **Hyperlinking** and either uncheck `Enable on demand hyperlink style navigation` or change `Default modifier key`.
I changed `Default modifier key` to `alt` .

Answer (score 1):

"In the newer report, `Jun Luo suggested` on Monday to unbind the keyboard shortcuts for cut, copy, and paste in Eclipse Preferences -> General -> Keys.  I tried removing the Ctrl+C binding and all week I have not experienced this issue, so I am calling it fixed.  My Mac-using coworker has not reported the issue recurring since removing the ⌘+C binding, either."

REFERENCE: http://aaron-kelley.net/blog/2012/05/ctrlc-to-copy-does-not-always-work-in-eclipse/#comment-440339